# bash script kill race condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, kill

I have a bash script which calls `kill $PID`, then waits for 2 seconds and if `$PID` still exists (by checking `ps`), it calls `kill -9 $PID` as a fallback. AFAIK, this is a very standard script to kill a process, found in many sample scripts on the net.

The script works fine (I am not worried about PID reuse here), but today I managed to catch a rare race condition where the process is still being killed in the 2 seconds, and the `kill -9 hangs`. Here is the `ps` output:

```
root     17172  0.0  0.0   7920  1668 ?        S    Jul16   0:00 /bin/kill -9 16635
root     17173  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Jul16   0:00 [kill] <defunct>
```

The `kill -9` is hanging because it has hit a defunct process (ie from the previous kill), ie `PID 16635` is the process already killed by the first kill.

If I do a `kill -9` on the `kill -9 process (PID 17172)`, then it is all good.

Is there anyway I can prevent the `"kill -9"` from hanging in the first place? It is a fallback to ensure that the process is killed within 2 seconds. I do not want to add another background check to check the fallback `kill -9`.

**Update**:

The best answer I could find is to use the timeout command on the `kill -9`:

`timeout -s 9 2 kill -9 $PID`

This will ensure that after 2 seconds, if the `kill -9` hangs, the timeout will issue a `kill -9` on it.

Comment: as in as the process is being killed, the kill -9 is trying to kill as well and hangs since the process already died? maybe you should check the return code of the first kill and then if it is an error code or something it shouldnt be to signal this process was killed try the kill -9.

Comment: Yes, you have summed it up perfectly. I am not checking the return code because the kill -9 is a fallback (catch all) to terminate the process if it is not killed for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a better way to check if the process is still alive, and if you should send the `kill -9`

```
kill [pid]
sleep 5
kill -0 [pid]
if [ $? -eq  0 ] ; then
  echo 'process not terminated'
  kill -9 [pid]
else
  echo 'process terminated'
fi
```

This uses the sending of a signal through kill to make sure you have permission to send a kill signal to the process `kill -0`. Which may be better then checking just if the `PID` is still alive. Then if if you do have access to the program terminate the program. The only other thing you can possible do is put in a longer sleep or something non trival like writing your own kill or checking the process state,etc.

Also you can do another sleep and then check for the race condition by seeing after like 20 seconds if the `kill -9` is still alive and then killing that process. Which would at least alleviate the stalling of the script but not solve the race condition.

Comment: Can you confirm that I will not face the same issue with the above script? Ie the kill -0 returns a 0 (first kill not finished yet), and the kill -9 hangs. Also, I cannot do another sleep in the same script as the kill -9 will hang. I would have to create a separate background check for defunct processes.

Comment: why dont you try to `fork` the `kill -9` then have the sleep done. I also can not confirm. Since the issue is really hard to replicate.

Comment: I have found a potential answer and put it as an update above, not sure if it will work, but theoretically it should solve the problem.

Comment: i was thinking of using a timeout since thats basically the only way to solve this. or maybe have a loop that is only broken once the program is killed and keeps running the kill with a timeout